# jQuery email availability fails to check when user uses autofill

Tags: jquery

I have a perfectly working jQuery function that checks if an email is available or not, however, if the browser presents them with autofill suggestions, it doesn't recognise that additional letters have been inputted. For example - user begins to inputs admin@admin.com, however, at "adm" they use autofill from the dropdown. The jQuery still thinks only adm has been inputted.

```
$(function () {
$('#email').keyup(function () {
    var email = $(this).val();
    if (email != '' && email.length > 6) {
        //$('.check').show();
        $('error').fadeIn(400).html
        var dataString = 'email=' + email;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pages/check_email.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 'Available') {
                    $('.check').html('Available');
                } else {
                    $('.check').html('Unavailable');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.check').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest doing an interval / throttled loop **only** when they have the textbox focused, testing to see if (regex-wise) it is even a valid email whatever@whatever.com, THEN send it to your AJAX. No point it killing your server until it's a valid email!

Comment: Please don't tag the question with `[jquery-validate]` if you're not really using that plugin.  Removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was saying with the testing with Regex (first) continuously **before** doing an AJAX call, this way when they have focus, even if they do use that autocomplete, after a bunch of milliseconds it'll trigger your AJAX and see if the email is taken.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r4rHH/)

```
var testInterval;

$('#email').on({
    focus: function () {
        var _this = $(this);

        testInterval = setInterval(function () {
            var val = _this.val();

            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(val)) {

                clearInterval(testInterval);
                // valid email
                // now do AJAX!
            }
        }, 100); 
    },

    blur: function () {
        clearInterval(testInterval);
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help! I'd say might be best to just run the interval every 100ms even, not sure why I put in half a second haha

Comment: The check works perfectly how ever, it returns unavailable for all emails! http://jsfiddle.net/5BkjL/, I think it's something to do with line 16?

Comment: In -frameworks- on the sidebar, you don't have jQuery (1.7.2 or higher) selected

Comment: I've amended it within the jsFiddle, unfortunately it still returns unavailable for all email addresses once it's been validated!

Comment: You can't run any AJAX within jsFiddle, you'd have to test this live on your own page unfortunately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23159/discussion-between-ben-little-and-mcpdesigns)

Answer (score 0):

2 things I want to advice you with:

1- don't hook your check with Keyup, this will check every time I enter/remove a single character, and this maybe just too much to check, instead, use blur.

2- I think you can try to disable Autocomplete for this form, or for specific elements inside it, util you figure out how to fix this issue.

example:

```
<form id="myForm" autocomplete="off" method="post">
```

from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_autocomplete.asp):

> The **autocomplete** attribute specifies whether a form should have
>   autocomplete on or off.
>
> When autocomplete is on, the browser automatically complete values
>   based on values that the user has entered before.
>
> Tip: It is possible to have autocomplete "on" for the form, and "off"
>   for specific input fields, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, I've taken your advice and added the AutoComplete into the form.

Comment: hope that this has fixed your problem. :)